# PrepareTape fails in my c++ code

Tags: c++, windows, backup, virtual

I have created a virtual tape library with [Firestreamer](https://www.cristalink.com/fs/) . I wrote a code in c++ that copies a file to that virtual tape. But when i try to prepare the tape with [PrepareTape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362532(v=vs.85).aspx) windows function, it fails. Below is a part of my code where i called the PrepareTape windows function.

```
                /*Tape Handle*/
                LPCWSTR tapeName = L"\\\\.\\Tape1";
                HANDLE tapeHandle = CreateFile(tapeName,
                    /*GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE*/  GENERIC_ALL,
                    0,
                    0,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                    0);
                if (tapeHandle == NULL)
                {
                    cout << "ERROR::Unable To Open  handle for the tape in this machine the error is ::" << GetLastError() << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    wcout << "The Handle for the tape :" << tapeName << " is created successfully" << endl;
                }
                /*Prepare Tape*/
                DWORD prepareTApeSuccess = PrepareTape(
                    tapeHandle,
                    TAPE_LOAD,
                    TRUE
                    );

                if (prepareTApeSuccess == NO_ERROR)
                {
                    cout << "Prepare Tape successsfully executed" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Prepare Tape Failed with the error :" << prepareTApeSuccess << endl;
                }
                if (!CloseHandle(tapeHandle))
                {
                    cout << "Close handle for the file is failed with thie error" << GetLastError() << endl;
                }
```

Output

```
The Handle for the tape :\\.\Tape1 is created successfully
Prepare Tape Failed with the error :1
```

But the rest of all i.e the other tape functions are working fine with the same handle. I tried to to get the status of the tape with GetTapeStatus function. The Tape device is ready to accept appropriate tape-access commands without returning errors, the return value is NO_ERROR.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the prepare tape function consider the third parameter, if this parameter is TRUE, the function returns immediately. If it is FALSE, the function does not return until the operation has been completed. I have changed it to false and my problem was resolved.